# C# Find all substring in large string with pattern

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

Consider I have the following string:

```
jkasdlue as 12&sdaj__3982[source=saj_/29]sj*2&7^;'asj[source=-js/.2]_jsld+=[source=283]
```

I'd like to get output of array of string below:

```
{"saj_/29","-js/.2","283"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Okay. Pardon me if my question is too broad or seems no effort from me.
I need to refine the pattern which should accept only alphanumeric characters, "-", "_", ".", "/", ":", " ". Follow someone suggestion below to use regex.

For now this regex seems to work:

```
\[source=[A-Za-z0-9-_ \\\/.:]+\]
```

Next step substring each match to eliminate the open tag "[source=" and the close tag "]"

Any better idea to reduce the process?

Comment: would you like some coffee as well?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post that too?

Comment: Google RegEx. It can accomplish what you're asking pretty easily.

Comment: @vks, What's with the attitude? The guy is obviously new here, how about welcoming him with something constructive? Moreover, why has this been marked as off-topic? He has tagged his question under C# and regex, indicating he is looking for a regular expression to solve his problem. He has also provided his input string and expected output. I really don't see the confusion here...

Comment: @Matt he is not new..... Or else I would have guided him.when he decided to use regex,he should have at least tried once....

Comment: @vks, new or not.. I don't see the necessity for sarcasm.. in any case, what's the problem with his question? It's very clear to me.

Comment: @Matt The problem is no attempts .... Do u want SO to be a code writing service ??

Comment: @vks, Calm down. Of course we should expect them to make an effort. However, instead of immediately closing his question, I think we should be asking him to update his answer with what he has already tried and give him a little time to do that before just shutting him down so quickly. With that kind of treatment, it's no wonder people are saying the SO community isn't what it used to be.

Comment: @Matt Its been 3 hrs....d question was not edited,no comments....I guess OP put it and forgot ....it can. Be reopened if he improves it...

Comment: @vks, Yeah.. I just get back outside from buying some coffee..

Comment: @Matt, thanks for your support. I think it's my fault. Sometimes I found some silly question in SO with little to no effort, but it has so many votes. Maybe he/she just so popular, so just put anything, it will have many votes. You know, just like facebook or twitter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `\[source=([A-Za-z0-9-_ \\/.:]+)\]` (if you do not need to match a backslash. remove `\\`) and access the value without last `]` and initial `[source=` using `match.Groups[1].Value`.

```
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[source=([A-Za-z0-9-_ \\/.:]+)\]").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/4xdTn1):

```
var str  = "jkasdlue as 12&sdaj__3982[source=saj_/29]sj*2&7^;'asj[source=-js/.2]_jsld+=[source=283]";
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[source=([A-Za-z0-9-_ \\/.:]+)\]").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", res));
```

Result:

```
saj_/29
-js/.2
283
```

Note that it is also possible to get the results using look-arounds, but as they are "expensive", less efficient and just not necessary here, I would not advise to use it. Here is link to a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5Bsource%3D)%5BA-Za-z0-9-_%20%5C%5C%2F.%3A%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5C%5D)&i=jkasdlue%20as%2012%26sdaj__3982%5Bsource%3Dsaj_%2F29%5Dsj*2%267%5E%3B%27asj%5Bsource%3D-js%2F.2%5D_jsld%2B%3D%5Bsource%3D283%5D):

```
(?<=\[source=)[A-Za-z0-9-_ \\/.:]+(?=\])
^^^lookbehind^                    ^^^^^^ - lookahead
```

And in C#:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=\[source=)[A-Za-z0-9-_ \\/.:]+(?=\])").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: so to set the pattern into groups we just need to put "(" and ")" ? I will try this one. Thank you.

Comment: Let's put it that way: in a .NET regex pattern, one should enclose a part of the pattern into unescaped parentheses in order to access submatches. When you need no overlapping matches and no specific context requirements, you need no lookarounds although that way you get a cleaner match result. Performance is key and capturing mechanism is most efficient and is available across almost all platforms.